# Chart set Vertical Bar Marker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, data-visualization

On my Chart, I want to put an obvious red vertical bar which goes from a specific point on the plot down to the x-axis.  Is there a way to do this?  Based on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it doesn't seem like this option is available or perhaps I'm looking in the wrong area.

Comment: You can either add a LineAnnotation or use a LineChart Series with two red points.. The latter is more work, though.. Are you using Winforms or WPF or ASP or what??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way is to add a `VerticalLineAnnotation`.

Here is an example:
[image]

First I set up a few things:

```
int yourPointIndex = 635;
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
ChartArea CA1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
```

Now I create the `Annotation` and style it a little:

```
VerticalLineAnnotation LA = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
LA.LineColor = Color.Red;
LA.LineWidth = 9;
LA.IsInfinitive = false;
LA.AnchorDataPoint = S1.Points[yourPointIndex]; ;
```

Now I position it with the `Point` in question:

```
LA.X = S1.Points[yourPointIndex].XValue;
LA.Y = S1.Points[yourPointIndex].YValues[0];

// this makes the bar go down to the zero axis
LA.Height = LA.Y;
// this makes it go down all the way to the x-axis:
LA.Height = LA.Y - CA1.AxisY.Minimum;
// we should clip it to our chartarea:
LA.ClipToChartArea = CA1.Name;
```

Finally it is added to the `Annotations` collection of the `Chart`.

```
chart1.Annotations.Add(LA);
```

Note that `Annotations` can be adorned and made to be moveable..

Note: The code above was written for and tested with `Winforms` but the MS `Chart` control is rather similar in all its versions..

Comment: Thanks, I can definitely get that to work.  Based on your graph, if I wanted to extend that line all the way down to the x-axis where it says 636, do I just set that `IsInfinitive` property to true?

Comment: Well, no, because that makes it go all the way __up and down__. (Try it!) You will have to know&use the Minimum YValue. I have aded a little to show you how to do it. Also do note the correction in the ClipToChartArea line..!!